# Can't reference json file in root

Tags: json, azure, configuration, azure-webjobs

I created a new Azure WebJobs project which is a console app. I placed a settings.json file in the root and I'm trying to access it using the following code but I keep getting an error that says it cannot locate the file. I think it's looking for it under Debug folder but I don't want to move the file there. How do I reference that file?

```
var config = new Configuration();
config.AddJsonFile("settings.json");
```

I tried "~/settings.json" but that didn't work either.

Comment: The settings file always gets copied to the debug/release folder depending on your build configuration. Why are you trying to load the file explicitly in the code?

Answer (score 0):

You need to identify if it's a deployment or runtime issue, per [this article](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Deployment-vs-runtime-issues).

Make sure that your file is in fact getting deployed:

- In VS, check that it has Copy to Output directory set to Copy if Newer
- Use [Kudu Console](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Kudu-console) to look at the relevant WebJob folder under `D:\home\site\wwwroot\App_Data\jobs\...` and make sure that the json file made it to there next to the exe.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add your json file into your WebJob project's Resources as shown:
Remember to set the file type as **Text** and encoding to **UTF-8**.

In your code, you can easily access your json file as string as below:

```
// The Resources property depends on your actual file name being referenced
var settingsJson = Resources.settings;
```

[image]

Hope this helps!